# highcharts column stroke in styled mode

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

When using highcharts with a column chart in styled mode, I cannot change the color of the column border (borderColor property in normal mode).

https://jsfiddle.net/ouaigooo/42xgm5r7/

Setting

```
.highcharts-point {
    stroke: black;
}
```

has no effect ! (stroke-width works, but not stroke)

In other words, how can I reproduce this in styled mode ?

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-borderwidth/

```
series: {
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'black'
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what is styled mode?

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to achieve, both stroke and stroke-width has an effect: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/v5dtobe0/2/

Comment: does not work with js/highcharts.js and @import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css'; why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stroke` style is overwritten, use stronger selector:

```
.highcharts-column-series rect.highcharts-point {
    fill: #FF0000;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r2h1kzqu/